# Is there any open source flow diagram library for angular that produce Json

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to Integrate a flow diagram (Task flow) in my angular project, that produce JSON and when I want to edit that diagram, it should be get edited with previous JOSN. My first preference is Open Source.